# Clone a phalcon project and Installing Phalcon on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phalcon

So, I git cloned a phalcon project to /var/www and ran composer install and it gives me the following error

- PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'phalcon' because required module 'psr' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
- phalcon/dd v1.1.3 requires ext-phalcon ^3.0 || ^4.0 -> the requested PHP extension phalcon is missing from your system.

So I understand that I have to install phalcon on my local environment first.

Before you point me to the document. I have already followed it and I am still very much lost on what to do.  In my opinion, it has the most confusing steps that I can't keep up.

This is what I did based on the documentation

a. git clone https://github.com/jbboehr/php-psr  and cd  php-psr
*PHP-PSR is now in /home/user/php-psr

b. phpize

c. ./configure

d. make

e.make test

f.sudo make install

g. Then I manually went to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php. ini  and added this two lines

- extension=psr.so
- extension=phalcon.so

h. sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

i. sudo pecl install phalcon

j. curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

k. sudo apt-get update

l. sudo apt-get install php7.2-phalcon

I am not too sure if i am missing any steps because their documentation is so jumbled up with installation steps of different OS .

So my question is how to know if phalcon is installed because i checked phpinfo() and nothing of phalcon was mentioned in it.

Thank you.